# Viewing the xml contents as tree view in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

In Xml We have around 1000 tags I want these to be viewed in tree view in EA without creating it has elements.So is this possible in EA

Comment: I simply don't understand your question.

Comment: We are trying to read the xml file and converting the xml contents to EA class elements through addin .Since there are large number of contents in xml file we don't want to display as diagram but for the end user we have to display only the xml contents in project browser.So without creating packages and elements can't we display the xml contents

Answer (score 0):

You can associate an element (e.g. artifact or class) with the XML file:

- Select the element in the browser
- In the docked properties window (`View/Properties`) set the `Filename` to your XML file
- Open `Package/Code Engineering/Show Source Viewer` (and possibly dock it somewhere).

Now each time you click on your element(s) with linked filenames the code editor will show the file contents. XML will be highlighted (as many other languages will).